# Passing data between components React-JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing an issue in passing data between components in React-JS. I have referred to various other solution on the platform but they didn't work for me.

In my parent component, I'm calling an API and setting it to a state. Below is my function getting rendered in `ComponentDidMount()`

```
importJSON(){
  return fetch ("https://bitbucket.org/..")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
       this.setState({
         data: responseJson.fulldata
       })
       console.log(this.state.data)
    })
}
```

I'm passing the value to child component which renders a chart visualization in D3 library. By using the below statement in render, the visualization is also being rendered in the parent component while it has to load only when the component is called.

`<ChordFinal value={this.props.data}/>`

In the child component, I'm calling it this way. `const data = this.props.value;` I'm getting undefined error when the data is pushed to console.

Where am I doing it wrong? I referred to various examples but couldn't achieve it. I want to pass the data to child component without the visualization being loaded when the parent component is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, clearly your data is not available at the time you try to load it.

As your child element receives `this.state.data` in the `render()` method, you know that render can be called even before the request in your `ComponentDidMount()` has finished.

In order to avoid to have the undefined error, you could:

First, check it before render the child. Just render only if data is present:

```
{ this.state.data && <ChordFinal value={this.state.data}/> }
```

Or in child component check value, before using it (I assume data is an object and set it as empty, for example.)

```
const data = this.props.value ? this.props.value : {};
```

I hope it helps!

**Update**

I see, please try to add the following method to the parent element:

```
actualCallback(data) {    
    if(data.fulldata)
        this.setState({
            data: data.fulldata
        })
    else
        console.error("Empty response")
}
```

and, update the `importJSON` as follows:

```
importJSON(){
    return fetch ("https://bitbucket.org/..")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
        this.actualCallback(responseJson)            
    })
}
```

and in the `render()` method, you could see the content of `state.data` every time it renders:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.data)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Tried the above combinations. It still gives undefined or null array in console.

Comment: Then add a little bit more of code to the question. Maybe we're missing something else out.

Comment: What part of code do I add here? I have added the function where API is being called and a state is being set to it. I just need to pass on the data assigned to this state to the child component.

Comment: I'll update the answer

Comment: This is now resolved. I had to pass the props through `route`. Many thanks for your help.